# PKCS12.new file.p12, passphrase -> throws "PKCS12_parse: unsupported" error after upgraded our rails app to Heroku-22 Stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, openssl

The following code worked fine on Heroku-18 stack

```
p12_file = File.read(uploaded_p12_file_path)
pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new p12_file, password
```

but after upgrading to Heroku-22 Stack the same code throws the following error:

```
PKCS12_parse: unsupported
```

The user can upload its p12 file with its password via an input form on the web.

We're using Ruby 3.1.2. Strangely, it works on the local development machines but not on Heroku. Does anyone have a clue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do your dependencies include openssl 1.1? If so - it looks like you might need to update your dependencies so you use openssl 3: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-22-stack#openssl-3

Comment: On Heroku  openssl3 is being used:
OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
=> "OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021"

But locally it's still openssl1.1 being used.
 OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
=> "OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022"

Is there a way to enforce the usage of openssl1.1? Or how can the p12 file updated to work with openssl3?

Comment: The docs linked state that you need to migrate to version 3, see the provided answer - it seems to be on point.

Answer (score 7):

I just got bit with the same error. There were a number of updates to the PKCS12 API in OpenSSL 3, among them a deprecation of [legacy algorithms](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/migration_guide.html#PKCS-12-API-updates) and that's what got us. Depending on your setup, if you are able to convert your certificate to X509 you should be able to get back on track. First thing is this: a p12 certificate contains both the certificate and its key in the same file. With X509 certificates, they need to be separate files. You can export them both with these commands:

```
# Export certificate
openssl pkcs12 -legacy -in my_certificate.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out my_certificate.pem

# Export key
openssl pkcs12 -legacy -in my_certificate.p12 -clcerts -nocerts -out my_certificate.key
```

I'm using them in an `SSLContext` which is the place where I add the private key:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new.tap do |ctx|
  ctx.add_certificate(
    OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("my_certificate.pem")),
    OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("my_certificate.key"), @cert_password),
    [@root_cert]
  )
end
```

I hope you can use the same concepts in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. That makes sense. In our case, we need a way to solve our problem automatically in our web app using Ruby on Rails (ruby/openssl). However, ruby/openssl doesn't provide the legacy option, so we are stuck here. For now, we downgraded to Heroku-20 stack which still uses openssl 1.1, until the provider of the certificate updates the format.

Comment: @Gerald when trying SSL communication with a webservice using PKCS12, on heroku-20, I had the following error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: dh key too small.  Are you using heroku-20 and pkcs12?  What's your version of Ruby? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, but I didn't see your comment. We use Ruby 3.0.4.

Answer (score 3):

I went through this problem and solved it, via ruby ​​code, regenerating the certificate. The source code is this one below: (hope it helps you)

```html
CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR = Rails.root / 'tmp' / 'certs'
Dir.mkdir(CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR) unless File.exists?(CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR)

cert_file =  "#{CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR}/my_cert.pfx"
cert_file_key = "#{CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR}/my_cert.key"
cert_file_pem = "#{CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR}/my_cert.pem"
cert_file_fix = "#{CERT_TEMPORARY_DIR}/my_cert_fix.pfx"

File.delete(cert_file_key) if File.exists?(cert_file_key)
File.delete(cert_file_pem) if File.exists?(cert_file_pem)
File.delete(cert_file_fix) if File.exists?(cert_file_fix)

pwd = '123456' # password

#execute openssl - bash
puts `openssl pkcs12 -legacy -in #{cert_file} -out #{cert_file_pem} -nodes -passin pass:#{pwd}`
puts `openssl pkcs12 -legacy -in #{cert_file} -nocerts -out #{cert_file_key} -passin pass:#{pwd} -passout pass:'#{pwd}'`
puts `openssl pkcs12 -export -out #{cert_file_fix} -inkey #{cert_file_key} -in #{cert_file_pem} -passin pass:#{pwd} -passout pass:#{pwd}`

File.delete(cert_file_key) if File.exists?(cert_file_key)
File.delete(cert_file_pem) if File.exists?(cert_file_pem)

cert_file = cert_file_fix
cert_content = File.read(cert_file)

cert = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(cert_content, pwd)
```