# Rails OpenSSL - PKCS12_parse: unsupported (OpenSSL::PKCS12::PKCS12Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm using HTTParty to connect to a host with a p12 file and password. Internally, the gem uses `OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(p12_file_content, 'password')`, so to test that, i ran this in my rails console:

```rb
p12_file_content = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/certs/#{Rails.env}_client_certificate.p12")
=> "0\x82\e\xF1\u0002" .......

OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(p12_file_content, 'myfakepassword')
```

Error:

```bash
`initialize': PKCS12_parse: unsupported (OpenSSL::PKCS12::PKCS12Error)
```

Then I tried to just read the file in my terminal:

```bash
openssl pkcs12 -info -in development_client_certificate.p12 -nodes

Enter Import Password:
```

And this works. Why does the OpenSSL ruby struggle with this cert?

(PS: I have other certs that do work with `OpenSSL::PKCS12.new`, and yes, I've tried the correct password a 100 times)

---

Versions:

```
irb(main):016:0> OpenSSL::VERSION
=> "3.0.1"
```

and

```
ruby -v
ruby 3.1.4p223 (2023-03-30 revision 957bb7cb81) [arm64-darwin22]

openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023)
```

I'm not sure if these matter? The gem's `3.0.1` is used for Ruby 3.1.4

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894224/pkcs12-new-file-p12-passphrase-throws-pkcs12-parse-unsupported-error-afte

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: dbugger's comment was correct. The other post that was linked, stated that the certificates were using a legacy format. It turns out that this was my case as well.

I tried converting my p12 certificate to a new format.

I already had the `.pem` and `.key` files, so I didn't need to extract them first.

So to just convert to a new format, I used this command (found elsewhere on the internet)

```
openssl pkcs12 -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -export -in development_certificate.pem -out my_new_cert.p12 -inkey development_client_certificate.key
```

Honestly, I have no idea what the `PBE-SHA1-3DES` algorithm is, or if others would work, but this one does :)

The new certificate now worked well with the OpenSSL gem in ruby :)